# How to use BC with negative exponentials?

Tags: bc

I want to use:

```
echo 'scale=6; sqrt(1/4670*1e-06)' | bc
```

But I get:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Comment: I don't think `bc` supports numbers in "e" notation - regardless of the sign of the exponent

Comment: how can I convert it to `1*10**-06` ?

Comment: Is `bc` your only option? you could consider awk or perl for example ex. `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.6f", sqrt(1/4670*1e-06)}'`

Comment: [How to get bc to handle numbers in scientific (aka exponential) notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12882611/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Since `bc` doesn't accept the `*1e-06` notation, you've gotta use `*10^(-6)`. I recommend you use

```
echo 'sqrt(1/(4670*10^(-6)))' | bc -l
```

The `-l` option loads bc's math library and sets the scale to 20.